# Lucene Taxonomy Facets: difference between Hierarchial and DrillDown search

Tags: lucene, faceted-search

When I index fields using Lucene's taxonomy mechanism, I can specify the hierarchial path:

```
var doc = new Document();
doc.add(new FacetField("Date", "2010", "10", "15"));
```

In the query, I can specify path in two places:

```
var query = new DrillDownQuery(config);
query.add("Date", "2010", "10"); // here

var collector = new FacetsCollector();
FacetsCollector.search(searcher, query, 10, collector);

var facets = new FastTaxonomyFacetCounts(taxoReader, config, collector);
var result = facets.getTopChildren(10, "Date", "2010", "10"); // here
```

Both places accept `String... path` as an argument. My simple tests show the same behavior in both cases. The question is, what's the difference and why we need 2 places to specify the path in a query?